# Universal Property of an Embedding

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

I've been reading through Tammo tom Dieck's text on algebraic topology and have been trying to prove a proposition (1.2.1) of his from the first chapter. Please find below an equivalent reformulation:

Let $i\colon Y \to A$ be a bijection and $g\colon Z\to Y$ a set map. If $g$ is continuous if and only if $i\circ g$ is continuous, then $i$ is a homeomorphism.

The converse was easy to show, but for this direction, I cannot seem to get my open sets to work out correctly - it's as though I need to push an open set forward but have no means of doing so. If anyone has any hints or tips, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: What about $g = i^{-1}$ ?

Comment: This might be where my (mis)understanding of the problem lies. I had been trying to show it for an arbitrary $g$, but is that not required?

Comment: Your formulation is at least superficially weaker than what's in the book (but is a special case, so that's fine enough), and the way you've worded it makes it sound like $Z$ and $g$ are fixed, whereas the statement is more like: "Let $i:Y\to A$ be a bijection, then if for any $Z$ and $g:Z\to Y$, $g$ is continuous if and only if $i\circ g$ is, then $i$ is a homeomorphism."

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! I am finally starting to understand the underlying categorical ideas again (we did similar proofs with other universal properties in general topology last semester). I appreciate your insightful comments Max and Henno Brandsma, and thank you Derek Elkins for a much better wording! I should be able to write down a concise proof now.

Comment: Note that $i$ is continuous by taking $g$ as the identity on $Y$ as a test map. And the universal property says that $Y$ has the initial topology w.r.t $i$. A bijective initial map is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone! Here is my attempt at a proof (feel free to critique):

Since our assumption holds for any such $Z$ and $g$, choose $Z=Y$ and $g=\mbox{id}_Y$, which is of course continuous. Then $i\circ \mbox{id}_Y = i$ is continuous. Similarly, choosing $Z=A$ and $g=i^{-1}$ shows that $i^{-1}$ is continuous. As a continuous bijection with continuous inverse, $i$ is a homeomorphism.

I much prefer the elegance of the solution by @HennoBrandsma in the comments above, but I would have definitely not thought of using the universal property in such a way! (I hope it will become easier to invoke for me as I study it more.)

Thank you again!